# MenuInflater in SherlockActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to get the menu inflater inflate the menu xml in my SherlockActivity class.

My onCreateOptionsMenu method is like this -

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = this.getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.messagespagemenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and my messagespagemenu.xml looks like this -

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:title="@string/deleteall">
</item>
```

And my activity class extends SherlockActivity.

Could anyone please point me to the mistake I am doing.

EDIT:

The menu is not showing. When I try this same code in another class is extending SherlockListActivity then it works. So I am wondering if I am missing anything in this class

Comment: @nasaa: Can you post an image of the problem? That ought to give some clarity to the issue you are facing. If it can be _shown_ that is.

Comment: @sid: I am trying to get the menu inflated from the xml and see it through the hardware menu key.

Comment: @nasaa: Okay. And when you click the hardware menu key, nothing pops up?

Comment: Try adding an icon along with the `android:showAsAction:always` or `android:showAsAction:ifRoom` as recommended by @OvidiuLatcu on your item. Also, remember, that because you are using the ActionBarSherlock menu, you will not get a conventional pre-honeycomb Menu.

Comment: But I want menu in the hardware menu. And if I use this code in SherlockListActivity then it works. So does this means that SherlockActivity has this limitation?

Comment: @nasaa: Please explain _menu in the hardware menu_. Do you mean you want the conventional pre-honeycomb menu?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are running this on a pre-Honeycom device, and this `MenuItem` will be shown just if you click the hardware `menu` key. You should set `android:showAsAction:always`or `android:showAsAction:ifRoom` on your `<item>`.

**EDIT:**  you should also make the call to `super.onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Yeah I am running on pre honeycomb device and That's why I used sherlock. I am trying to see it on the hardware menu itself but then also it does not show.

Comment: Tried that and that made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if this works:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflate = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflate.inflate(R.menu.messagespagemenu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Also, make sure this part looks exactly like in this sample above:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

You currently have this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu)
```

I am not sure if that makes any difference or not, but see it works. The corresponding `import` should be `import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;`

Comment: Sorry Sid. Tried exactly what you said and still no luck.

Comment: Hmm... And you want the menu to look like it does in ICS or you want it to look like it did before honeycomb?

Comment: Aaah. So like this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu? _Figure 1. Options menu in the Browser, on Android 2.3_

Comment: How does it look when you are SherlockListAvtivity? Like it does in ICS or pre honeycomb?

Comment: me too :( this should have been a simple job..thanks for trying.

Comment: No problem. Glad to have _tried_ to help. Let me see if I can still get it to work. Just out of curiosity, can you post the image of the menu when you are extending `SherlockListActivity`?